# How to use a adb like backup command on android phone

Tags: android, backup, adb

I'm interested in using a general backup command like: **adb backup -f at_all_app.ab -noapk com.at_all_app** on an android 4.1 mobile to backup an app (an 'at all' app) to the mobils SD Card.

I try to use this command in the android terminal (shell) to backup something to SD Card but, how wonder, *unable to connect for backup* was the system answer. The reason for this will be, that there exists no adb-client-server pair, i guess. Normally you have a server client pair form the PC to the android mobil.

Is there any way/idea to implement a code to backup a foreign installed package (not the apk) on an android phone SD Card without a PC like the adb command I wrote above?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your updating your phone's internal system, you may want to backup individual files instead of the entire phone data in a single file. For that purpose, I use adb pull with a little trick. First, I list what I want into a file named `folders.txt`, then I run this batch below:

```sh
# this is go.sh
while read p; do
  file=$1$p
  if [ -e "$file" ]
  then
    echo Already exists: "$file"
  else
    echo Reading: "$file"
    adb pull "$file"
  fi
done < folders.txt
```

Example:

```sh
chmod +x ./go.sh  # make it executable
ls sdcard > folders.txt # get the list of desired files, and edit it if needed
./go.sh sdcard # run this, as many times you need
```